# If $T_t$ is a diffeomorphism and $t\mapsto T_t(x)$ is differentiable, can we find a map $v$ with $v(t,T_t(x))=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function-theorem, diffeomorphism, inverse-function-theorem

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\tau>0$, $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open and $T_t$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$ with $T_0=\operatorname{id}_U$. Note that $$V:=\bigcup_{t\in[0,\:\tau)}T_t(U)$$ is open.

> Assume $[0,\tau)\ni t\mapsto T_t(x)$ is differentiable for all $x\in U$. Can we show (under suitable additional assumptions, if necessary) that there is a $v:[0,\tau)\times V\to\mathbb R^d$ with $$v\left(t,T_t(x)\right)=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)\tag1$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau)\times V$?

If $U=\mathbb R^d$ (and hence $V=\mathbb R^d$), we may simply set $$v(t,x):=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}\left(t,T_t^{-1}(x)\right)\tag2.$$

**EDIT 1**: I want to choose $v$ such that it is (jointly) continuous. By assumption, $$[0,\tau)\times U\ni(t,x)\mapsto T_t(x)\tag3$$ is partially differentiable in both the first and the second variable. So, it should be differentiable and hence (jointly) continuous.

**EDIT 2**: I wonder whether any differentiability properties of $v$ with respect to the second variable carry over to $v$. I've found the following excerpt in a [book](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642634710), which seems to indicate this, but I actually don't understand how they conclude (2.76):
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for a function $v:[0,\tau)\times V\to\mathbb R^d$ satisfying:

$v\left(t,T_t(x)\right)=\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x) \qquad \forall (t,x)\in[0,\tau)\times U\tag1$

Fix $\bar{t}\in [0,\tau)$. The equation:
$$v\left(\bar{t},T_\bar{t}(x)\right)=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(\bar{t},x) \qquad \forall x \in U $$
is a condition on the value of $v(\bar{t}, \cdot)$ on the set $T_\bar{t}(U)$. It can be restated as follows:
$$v\left(\bar{t},y\right)=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(\bar{t},T_\bar{t}^{-1}y) \qquad \forall y\in T_\bar{t}(U)$$

Consider now the set
$$A := \bigcup_{t \in [0,\tau)} \big(\{t\}\times T_t(U)\big)  \subseteq [0,\tau)\times V$$

and define $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^d$ as follows:
$$
f(t,y):=
\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,T_t^{-1}y) \qquad \forall  (t,y)\in A
$$
Then $(1)$ is equivalent to the following:
$$ v(t,y)=f(t,y) \qquad \forall (t,y) \in A$$

If you don't mind continuity of $v$, you can define $v$ on $A^c:=[0,\tau)\times V - A$ arbitrarily and to be equal to $f$ on $A$.

### LOOKING FOR CONTINUITY

If you need $v$ continuous (or even more regular), then the problem is whether $f$ admits a continuous (or even more regular) extension to the set $[0,\tau)\times V$.

In what follows, we will consider only the simpler case in which $T_t(U)=U $ for all $ t \in [0,\tau)$.

In this case, $A=[0,\tau)\times V = [0,\tau)\times U$ and thus $v$ and $f$ must be the same function. Therefore, $v$ is necessarily defined as follows:
$$
v(t,y):=
\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,T_t^{-1}y) \qquad \forall  (t,y)\in A
$$

If we assume

- $(t,x)\mapsto\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)$ is **jointly** continuous in $t,x$.
- $(t,y)\mapsto T_t^{-1}(y)$ is **jointly** continuous in $t,y$.

then $v(t,y)$ is jointly continuous in $t,y$ since it is the composition of the continuous mapping $(t,y)\mapsto (t,T_t^{-1}(y))$ with the continuous mapping $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}$.

Be aware that if $(t,x)\mapsto\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)$ or $(t,y)\mapsto T_t^{-1}(y)$ lack of jointly continuity then it is in general unlikely for $v$ to be jointly continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I thought this definition of $v$ is not suitable, is that I surely want $v$ to be jointly continuous. However, the assumptions should imply that $(3)$ is differentiable (on the product space) and hence (jointly) continuous. So, your map $v$ should be jointly continuous as well, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well, this is a different question :). I'll think about it and modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to assume that $T_t(U)=U$. This is actually what the reference I've added to the question seems to do. Do you see how they conclude (2.76)?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Do you have any thoughts on (2.76)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I suspect it is a matter of function spaces definition. Can you please tell me how is $C^0(0,\epsilon; C^k(\bar{D},\mathbb{R}^N))$ is defined in the book? Moreover, nowhere it is stated that $T$ can be derived with respect to $t$, nontheless $\partia T / \partial t$ appears...

Comment: $C^0(E_1,E_2)$ is the space of continuous functions equipped with the supremum norm, whenver $E_1$ is a topological space and $E_2$ is a normed space. In this case, $E_2=C^k(\overline D,\mathbb R^N)$ and it is equipped with the usual norm given by the suprema of all derivatives (as presented here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition#H%C3%B6lder_spaces).

Comment: @0xbadf00d Ok, if the book uses the standard notation then I also doubt that the line immediately after (2.74) holds...

Comment: Yeah, it's terrible. There is also a [newer book](https://books.google.de/books?id=xkOtFbs2pX0C&pg=PR10&lpg=PR10&dq=%22basic+formula+for+boundary+integrals%22&source=bl&ots=tnUAQXHdgh&sig=ACfU3U3BbNL_ZzU6QAUFnSo_UIJNnQxTPQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie8tv6vNzqAhWClqQKHVaKCYQQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22basic%20formula%20for%20boundary%20integrals%22&f=false), but it is written by one of the authors of the other book and contains exactly the same dubious claims and results. Unfortunately, they seem to be the most cited reference on shape optimization ...

Comment: Well... good luck!

Comment: Regarding your continuity considerations: I think we don't need to explicitly assume that $(t,x)\mapsto\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)$ is continuous. In fact, by assumption, this map is separately differentiable in both $t$ and $x$. Assuming that the corresponding derivatives are continuous, it should follow that this map is jointly differentiable and hence jointly continuous. Right? Oh, and it should generally hold that $v$ is separaetely continuous in both arguments.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't think so. In general, the jointly continuity of partial derivatives of a function allow to state that the function is differentiable and hence (jointly) continuous.

Comment: Huh? In which point do you disagree with what I wrote?

Comment: @0xbadf00d 1) Existence of partial derivatives is not equivalent to differentiability.
2) look at the definition of $v$: if the functions involved are separately continuous in each argument, then $v(t,y)$ will be continuous in its second argument $y$. But, moving its first argument $t$ would change at the same time both arguments of $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}$. For this reason I think you need jointly continuity of $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ if you want $v$ to be continuous in the $t$ variable.

Comment: (1) Existence of *continuous* partial derivatives *is* equivalent to continuous differentiability. Did you miss that or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I agree with you on this. I probably misunderstood your comment before. However what is tacit is that jointly continuous partial derivatives is equivalent to continuous differentiability. If the partial derivatives are continuous only separately in each variable, which is our starting assumption (did I miss something?), then this does not mean that (global) differentiability nor continuity hold (in general).